# Lubuntu boots into terminal | Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, xorg, boot-repair

After a sudden power failure, my machine(`Lubuntu 16.04`) is facing the same issue described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514215/xserver-error-could-not-create-lock-file).

My machine is booting into a terminal. 
And when i execute `startx` command, it gives :

```
(EE) Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock
```

So in order to execute `sudo X -configure` i ran the below command and got error described below.

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /

[2112.489077] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_remount:4667: Abort forced by user
mount: cannot remount /dev/sda1 read-write, is write-protected
```

So I boot into a live system and chose *rescue a broken system* and in a shell with `/dev/sda1` mounted to `/` and executed the following commands

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

And it executes without any errors.

After I executed the following

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda1
```

The result was clean with no errors.

After that, i executed the following command.

```
sudo X -configure
```

then the machine restarted itself and got the same `they` which I described in the first part of this question.

**Update**

I tried another live image of `Ubuntu 16.04`.

Now when i run `fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda5` from the live image, it says `/dev/sda5` is mounted.

But when i run `umount /dev/sda5` it says `/dev/sda5` is not mounted.

I believe the issue is with my `/dev/sda5` partition. Am i correct?

How can I fix my machine? Any small help would be appreciated

Comment: Look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74090/linux-how-to-change-hdd-state-from-readonly-after-temporarly-crash

Comment: No luck, both commands `blockdev --setrw /dev/sda` and `hdparm -r 0` executed successfully, and got response for `hdparm` as `readonly = 0`. But still unable touch or execute `X-configure`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i managed to fix the issue.

The issue was due to corrupted(not really) entry for swap partition in my `/etc/fstab`. Swap entry was `/dev/sda5` instead of its `UUID`.

I believe the system failed to detect my swap partition from `fstab` and caused this issue turning my all file system read only.

So replacing the swap name from `/dev/sda5` to its `UUID` in `/etc/fstab` from a live USB fixed the issue.

But i haven't changed anything in `/etc/fstab` before this issue started and don't know why this issue happened.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409490/what-is-the-real-benefit-of-using-uuids) answer explains why we need to add `UUID` in `fstab` instead of `/dev/sd_`